# Creating array of object in loop in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

When I create an object of type `Deck`, an exception is shown: "indexoutofrangeexception was unhandled"

Can someone explain why?

```
public class Deck {
    Card[] card = new Card[52];
    const int NumOfCards = 52;

    public Deck()
    {
        string[] symbol = { "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades"};
        string[] rank = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", 
                          "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        for (int i = 0; i < card.Length; ++i)
        {
            /// this is the line with problem shown in debug                 
            card[i] = new Card(symbol[i / 13], rank[i % 13]);   
        }    
        Console.WriteLine(card.Length);
    }

    public void PrintDeck()  {
        foreach (Card c in card)
            Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `i % 13` value, then count items in `rank`, then look for `"Ten"`

Comment: Pff Zerk, I feel bad for posting as an answer now :)

Comment: @Rawling: put http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error there and it will be fine :-)

Comment: why the close vote? this is very good question for SO.

Comment: symbol has an off-by-nine error. I wonder why the OP uses card.Length, but not symbol.Length and rank.Length.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is in line

```
card[i] = new Card(symbol[i / 13], rank[i % 13]);
```

In the sentence

```
rank[i % 13]
```

when `i` is equal to 12, we got 12 % 13 = 12, and then `rank[12]` is an array position that not exists. To solve it, change 
    `rank[i % 13]`
by
    `rank[i % 12]`